# Classification of time-series according to the time intervals in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, pattern-matching

I have several time series in a dataframe. The idea is detecting those ids that have shorter time between periods recently rather than the past and distinguish them from the others. After detecting them, I want to assign them to a specific class.
I am not looking for any codes, just want to get some ideas and hints to figure out the best approach. The following table is just a part of the data as a sample to show how it looks like. Thank you.

| id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2/2/2016 | 24 |
| 24 | 2/4/2016 | 56 |
| 25 | 2/3/2016 | 135 |
| 23 | 3/4/2016 | 46 |
| 24 | 3/8/2016 | 176 |
| 25 | 3/9/2016 | 23 |
| 23 | 3/16/2016 | 98 |
| 24 | 3/13/2016 | 114 |
| 25 | 3/17/2016 | 43 |

Comment: Was there an independent attempt at a solution?

Comment: are the period times contained in the ids? you could make another column of "period time difference" and sort it with pandas. you cou could have some threshold and search through the time difference column, then send specific ones to a class.

Comment: could you explain the problem more deeply, like you got three ids, and each ids have three time points, what would you like to detect and what does shorter time mean

Comment: agree with BH0001, period time difference and find the shorter time and classify them apart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/19854159/kaispace30098 The table is just a sample to show how the data look like. I have thousands of ids and dates with different ranges. The whole idea is identify those ides that have shorter time intervals recently rather than the past and categorize them to a different class.   Shorter intervals in recent time will help me which id is becoming a concern.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/20619073/bh10001 Thank you for your comment. What types of classification algorithm would help for clustering in that case?